# How to do unit testing for methods that take parameters

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic, tdd

Lets say I have a `someMethod` that takes a `String` and `int` or **any other type** as its inputs.

When I want to write my Unit tests for this `someMethod`, am I to populate the method with my own given String and Int and then run it through my tests? Wouldn't that make my tests dependent to my input?

And presumably their value (the string and int input) is coming from another function, I should have a separate unit test for that function as well right?

Comment: Why don't you create a function or functions that will return random string/int output to be used in your tests? Therefore it will test a wide range of values.

Comment: @ToddVrba  I am a newbie so I never thought of that. I guess I could do that.

Comment: @ToddVrba It's usually not a good idea to use random data in a unit test. This could result in the test passing on one compile and failing on another for no comprehensible reason. Instead you should construct several typical input values and test them, ensuring consistency between runs. The trick is being comprehensive in your input values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions (or methods) that rely solely on their parameters for input (and not global/instance state) and their return value for output are actually the **easiest** to test. They're called [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). It's becoming increasingly popular to strive to have as much code exist in "pure" functions, because of how easily testable they are.

You give them sample input (from hardcoded values, a mock framework, test database, etc.), and you compare the output with what you expected.

On the other hand, dealing with non-pure functions/methods in tests is much harder. You need to set up an instance's state to a particular precondition, call the method to be tested, then test the instance after mutation. It's a much longer process.

Comment: So you don't check for nil values? That should be done by the development code through: if lets or simply crash your app with forced unwrapping?

Comment: Your sample inputs should cover the full range of edge cases you can think of, including `nil` input (when you're dealing with optional parameters), non-sense input, etc.

Comment: is that being redundant? shouldn't that already be done in your actual development code?

Comment: No, not at all. Your app code handles the edge cases, your unit tests provide your app code with edge cases to try to break it.

Comment: When you're writing a test, your mindset shouldn't be "What's some nice input I can give that can make my code run through its happy path so that  I can get my green checkmark?" Your mind set should be "What input can I give to make this break, to truly ensure i've covered my bases?"

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov That's the most important, of course. Testing to see if the code can handle unexpected input. However, it is also important to test expected input and output to be informed if a code change breaks functionality.

Comment: @ColGraff Well yes, gotta cover the full gamut of possible input, as per your business requirements

Comment: I have a function that takes 2 strings for alertTitle & messageString of a UIAlertViewController, so my function doesn't return anything as its output it only passes the values to the UIAlertViewController and then presents the AlertView. How am I suppose to test this function?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UIAutomation.html

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are mostly for testing interfaces, you have defined behaviors for your code and you're testing those behaviors. For example, you have a set of code that capitalizes a `String`. You would pass in a couple of different sets of text and verify that they work:

```
Input | Expected Output | Rationale
-------------------------------
test  | TEST            | all lower
Test  | TEST            | initial caps
tEst  | TEST            | middle caps
tesT  | TEST            | last caps
foo   | FOO             | checking different string
1foo  | 1FOO            | mixed string
```

etc...

Yes, you should make your unit tests comprehensive and try to cover as much code as possible. You can test individual functions but it's more important to test interface of objects, protocols, and important standalone functions. That's why it's called a unit test, you are testing a block or unit of code - not individual pieces.

Comment: So each would be a different testCase? I would have TestAllLower, TestInitialCaps, etc?

Comment: Ideally, yes. However it may make sense to combine several test cases into one test if they are testing similar capabilities. You should look at it this way: if a test case fails how difficult will it be to figure out what made it fail? Multiple test cases in one test adds complexity to the test.

Comment: You mean I put multiple Asserts in one case instead of having one assert per case?

Comment: Yes, a call to `assert` will only break if it fails so you can use multiple in a single case: "In playgrounds and -Onone builds (the default for Xcode's Debug configuration): if condition evaluates to false, stop program execution in a debuggable state after printing message." - [`assert`, SwiftDoc](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/func/assert/#func-assert_-bool_-string-file_-staticstring-line_-uint)